# Am I making some mistake in proving that $S$ is dense subset of $C[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider the space $X=C[0,1]$ with its usual 'sup-norm' topology.Let
$$S= \{ f \in X : \int_{0}^{1} f(t) dt \neq 0\}$$

> Show that $S$ is dense in $X$

We note that convergence with sup norm is uniform convergence.Suppose $ f_n \to f$ in $C[0,1]$  with sup-norm.So lim$_{ n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n dt$ =$ \int_{0}^{1}$  lim$_{ n\to \infty} f_n dt=\int_{0}^{1} f dt$.So if $f_n$ is in $S$ then $f$ is also in $S$.So $S$ is not dense,but I am suppose to prove that $S$ is dense.Please tell me my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence with $a_n \ne 0$ for all $n$.
Suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$. Do you can conclude $a \ne 0$?